# document.getElementsByClassName('className') gives undefined when its not

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on a program in Angular 2 and in a page I need to inject a Google form.

When the user is sending the form there is a button that gives the filled form and the result.
After that the user click on a button to continue.
The problem is when I use the function:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('quantumWizButtonNestedLink exportButtonNestedLink')[0].getAttribute("href");
```

When I type it to the console the chrome say:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

but if I click on the button that contain the href with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (that gives me the code of this button) and then I write in the console `"document.getElementsByClassName..."` its gives me the wanted href...

Does anyone have a solution for it?

Comment: my guess is you are calling it before it is on the page.... It is like calling for a person by name before they enter the room, they are not going to hear you. You need to wait until the page is ready and they are there.

Comment: Maybe your `document.getElementByClassName` code is executing before the element is actually rendered, try wrapping it in a timeout

Comment: When is this being called? What's your HTML?

Comment: I call Jinx! Everyone owes me a Coca Cola mwahaha

Answer (score 0):

in the code there is a survey of google form that the user need to answer.
when the user is finished to fill it there is a button to continue to the next step.
when the user press the button the system need to take the 'href' of the result of the filled survey.
but when the user press on the button in the log of the chrome print an error massage the the attribute is undefined 
this is the code:

```
<p>  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-link font"id="home">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home
    </button></p>
        <div class="ttl">
             <h1>Fill the next survey</h1>
        </div>
     <div class="ggl">
        <iframe class="gglFrm" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1m2Oqlrvz2ftgGnYOjNlkgl0WrJrbA23ZtyMwidPOq7s/viewform?chromeless=1&edit_requested=true"></iframe>
</div>
<p>  <button (click)="nxt()" type="button"  class="btn btn-link font">

         Press to continue 
        </button></p>
```

and the button function is :
  nxt()
  {

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('quantumWizButtonNestedLink exportButtonNestedLink')[0].getAttribute("href");
```

}

notice : for now the nxt function just need to take the 'href'